# JPA gives error on excuting named query using MySQL MATCH function

Tags: mysql, jpa

Named Query goes thus:

`@NamedQuery(name = "Table.findFTS", query = "SELECT t FROM table t WHERE MATCH(t.field1, t.field2) AGAINST (':text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")`

and the Error:

`Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Businesses.findFTS: SELECT t FROM table t WHERE MATCH(t.field1, t.field2) AGAINST (':text' IN BOOLEAN MODE)], line 1, column 38: unexpected token [(]. Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])`

I dunno why am getting this but it seems the MATCH function is giving it a headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're executing a query in JPQL than remember that you're not using SQL but JPQL. As far as I know there is no 'MATCH' function in JPQL. However, you might be interested in NamedNativeQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported out-of-the-box:

When using Hibernate you would have to create your own dialect:

```
public class MyMySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect {
    public MyMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("match", new MatchFunction(new AnyType(),"?1 AGAINST ?2"));
    }
}
```

I guess EclipseLink offers similar stuff.

Comment: Hi, I think your idea is good!but what is the second parameter of registerFunction() ?